# Brand new AngularFullstack app won't deploy to Heroku

Tags: heroku, deployment, angular-fullstack

I'm having trouble deploying my app to Heroku.  I don't have this issue with an app I started several months ago so I think it must be something wrong with the lastest Angular Fullstack.  After several hours of trouble shooting I decided to start from scratch just to see if AngularFullstack would deploy if you create a completely fresh app in an empty directory.

I created the app in the terminal with:
yo angular-fullstack

Without doing anything else I deployed the app to Heroku by typing this in the terminal:
yo angular-fullstack:heroku

Finally I went to the Heroku webaddress and I get the following "Application Error":
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

When I look at the Heroku logs I get the exact same error I was getting in my finished project:

Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '/app/dist/public/favicon.ico'

I've tried putting this file everywhere in my directory structure.  There is no 'dist' in directory structure of the new app.  I put this directory in the old app with grunt serve:dist but that doesn't fix the problem of locating favicon.ico even though it is there in the public folder. There is no 'app' directory at the top however and it begins looking all the way in my Mac 'User' path.  I think this part of the problem that I don't know how to fix.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problems Deploying to Heroku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606586/problems-deploying-to-heroku)